# Stretching a Graph to Fill the Canvas Element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, graphing

Quick question involving javascript canvas... I have a set points (connected with a line) I want to graph on a 400x300 canvas element. I will constantly be adding more points. I need the line to stretch to fill the entire canvas (leaving no unnecessary space).

Example:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Thanks! C.Ruhl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the step by doing `canvasWidth / (number of points - 1)`

and adding X += step each time.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pDDTQ/

Comment: I have both x and y coordinates. Also, what happens if the points go beyond the canvas height and width?

Answer (score 0):

Distinguish between internal canvas size and visible size. 400x300 is your visible size and set by style="width:400px; height:300px". Everytime there is new point (e.g. 400,500) you set canvas.width=400; canvas.height=500; and replot the whole graph. From a certain point you might want to adjust the width of the line.